# « Faire mine de + infinitif »

Tags: sens, constructions, france

*La Petite Fadette*, George Sand

L'expression « Faire mine de + infinitif » est bien connu en français moderne.

> (TLFi) − **Faire mine de + inf**. Faire semblant de + inf.
> • Parfois, je faisais mine de me passionner pour une cause étrangère à ma vie la plus quotidienne. Dans le fond pourtant, je n'y participais pas (Camus, Chute, 1956, p.1499).

Dans l'histoire de Sand on trouve l'usage suivant.

> Mais, au moment où il allait appeler Sylvinet, qui ne le voyait pas encore, et ne faisait pas mine de l'entendre, à cause du bruit de l'eau qui grouillait fort sur les cailloux en
> cet endroit, il s'arrêta à le regarder;

On est enclin de comprendre « et ne faisait pas semblant de l'entendre », ce qui n'a pas de sens dans le contexte de cette phrase. Que pourrait signifier cet usage à la forme négative ? Serait-ce simplement une forme alternative (et apparemment problématique) de « faisait mine de ne pas l'entendre » ? Y aurait-il une erreur ?

Answer (score 2):

Il s'agit ici d'une forme de transfert de la négation. La négation est appliquée *syntaxiquement* au semi-auxiliaire, mais *sémantiquement* liée au verbe infinitif. Cette construction grammatical est la forme normale pour d'autre semi-auxiliaires français:

> *Il ne faut pas en manger* (c'est à dire: "I faut éviter d'en manger" et non "il n'est pas obligatoire d'en manger")
>
> *Il ne semble pas voler* (c'est à dire: "I semble ne pas voler", du moins par défaut, car on peut aussi dire "il ne *semble* pas voler, il vole bel et bien")

C'est particulièrement évident dans l'usage du futur proche, où il est totalement impossible d'appliquer la négation à "venir":

> *Je ne vais pas manger* (c'est à dire: "je ne mangerai pas")

Ici, il faut dont comprendre *Il ne fit donc pas mine de s’en apercevoir* comme "il fit semblant de ne pas s'en apercevoir". À mon avis, c'est un usage pas nécessairement *incorrect*, mais extrêmement inhabituel en français contemporain. Ce genre de transformation est généralement rejeté lorsqu'on tente de l'appliquer à des expression toute faites come *faire mine de*.

Il n'est pas impossible qu'il s'agisse d'un usage dialectal berrichon: Sand était originaire du Berry et familière avec cet usage. Elle a même rédigé des articles sur le sujet.

---

**Addendum:** On me reproche le manque de source dans les commentaires. J'avais d'abord eu connaissance de ce phénomène dans un contexte de conlanging (Advanced Language Construction, pp. 151-152). J'étais plus préoccupé de confirmer d'autres exemples en français que de fournir des sources supplémentaires (voici déjà un [article sur le sujet](https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/fileSendAction/fcType/0/fcOid/583405316545421238/filePointer/583123841538308913/fodoid/583123841538308911/Article.pdf)).

Ceci dit, mon *Bon usage* (14e édition, 2007) en parle à la section §1020 (c). De fait, il y a même une note expliquant que cela a déjà été une construction générale et cite spécifiquement le verbe *faire semblant* comme ayant déjà fait usage de précisément cette construction (citations de La Bruyères et Jean-Jacques Rousseau).

Je crois donc que chez Sand, il s'agit d'une usage dialectal ou volontairement archaïsant, ou les deux à la fois.

Comment: Bien que j'ai considéré cette possibilité, c'était plutôt pour la forme, je n'y croyais vraiment pas. C'est très surprenant. Je suppose que si aucune référence n'a été jointe à cette réponse c'est que  sans de longues recherches sur le Web  il n'y a pas de chance d'en trouver.

Comment: @LPH La raison c'est que la personne a une expertise dans le domaine, contrairement à nous.

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle La raison de quoi ?

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle « à cause du bruit de l'eau » rend l'interprétation "faire semblant » impossible, remarque très juste.

Comment: Merci, j'étais le premier à faire +1 sur ta réponse, ce n'était pas un « reproche ». Mais donc tu interprètes ça comme « Il faisait semblant de ne pas l'entendre à cause du bruit de l'eau » ? Est-ce possible de faire semblant à ce degré-là selon toi ?

Answer (score 1):

Il s'agit d'une oeuvre bien connue et souvent rééditée et l'autrice emploie aussi la tournure identifiée en question un certain nombre de fois dans le sens de « faire semblant » et je ne pense pas qu'il y ait erreur. Un autre [extrait](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/La_Petite_Fadette/Texte_entier) :

> Landry, se voyant tout près de la petite Fadette, n’osa la regarder,
> et **fit mine de se retourner**, comme pour voir si les poulains le
> suivaient. Quand il regarda devant lui, la Fadette l’avait déjà
> dépassé, et elle ne lui avait rien dit : il ne savait même point si
> elle l’avait regardé, et si des yeux ou du rire elle l’avait sollicité
> de lui dire bonsoir. Il ne vit que Jeanet le sauteriot qui, toujours
> traversieux et méchant, ramassa une pierre pour la jeter dans les
> jambes de sa jument. Landry eut bonne envie de lui allonger un coup de
> fouet, mais il eut peur de s’arrêter et d’avoir explication avec la
> sœur. **Il ne fit donc pas mine de s’en apercevoir** et s’en fut sans
> regarder derrière lui.
>
> [ *La Petite Fadette* (1849), George Sand, éd. Calmann-Lévy, 1926. ]

Dans le deuxième cas on n'a pas dit exactement « il fit donc mine de ne pas s'en apercevoir » mais ça ressemble à *faire mine de rien*, *faire comme si de rien n'était*, ne manifester aucun sentiment, aucune réaction (TLFi). Mais plus généralement je pense qu'on parle du sens de montrer par sa physionomie (aujourd'hui c'est surtout le visage) sa réaction ou son état d’esprit :

> Vous avez vu sans doute ces MM. Hachette. Quelle mine ont-ils fait en
> lisant ma lettre? (Hugo, au TLFi)

Dans l'exemple de la question je pense qu'on revient au sens premier de [*mine*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/mine) soit l'« apparence naturelle du visage et de tout le corps qui révèle sentiments ou qualité, fortune ou rang social ». Donc rien ne laissait paraître ou ne montrait chez Sylvinet qu'il avait vu son frère s'approcher, à cause du bruit de l'eau, et d'ailleurs à la fin du paragraphe on trouve « et ne bougeant non plus qu’une pierre ». L'autrice ne semble pas du tout craindre avec la négation que la séquence de mots soit autrement identique à la locution signifiant « faire semblant de ».

Comment: second extrait, cas 1 : pas de problème, c'est la définition du TLFi, en forme affirmative. second extrait, cas 2 :  c'est soit le négatif de la définition, donc erroné, soit autre chose que « faire semblant », et la définition manque dans le TLFi. / « ça ressemble » est bien trop vague pour expliquer quoi que ce soit.  /  « on revient au sens premier » : dans ce cas ce n'est pas « faire mine » mais « faire **une** mine ». (Fam. Faire la mine; faire sa mine; faire grise mine; faire une mine de trois pieds de long.)

Comment: On verra, peut-être que quelqu'un aura une explication plus directe mais au contexte on ne peut faire autrement que comprendre quelque chose de différent de _faire semblant_ et j'ai personnellement assez d'indices pour saisir avec précision ce que l'autrice exprime et j'ai la certitude qu'elle possède parfaitement la langue.

Comment: Non, je ne crois pas qu'elle prenne tant de liberté avec la langue de son temps ; peut-être qu'elle a tendance à utiliser le vocabulaire régional plus que d'autres auteurs, mais c'est autre chose. On s'aperçoit que dans le sens du TLFi, le seul reconnu, cette expression  ne s'emploie pratiquement pas à la forme négative (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=elle+fit+mine+de%2Celle+ne+fit+pas+mine+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3), ce qui correspond à son sens ; le plus probable est qu'il y a deux sens, que dans ce second sens elle  s'emploie surtout (1/2)

Comment: à la forme négative ou même exclusivement (on n'en finirait pas de se demander ce qui est dit autrement). Ce qui est sûr, c'est que dans ce cas la définition manque, et il en faut une.  (2/2)

Comment: Il n'y a que 7 cas de « faire mine » à la voix affirmative.

Comment: Hugo se pose bien la question sur la mine que les Hachette ont fait en réaction à quelque chose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144309/discussion-between-lph-and-crissy-froth-seapickle).